# Multiselect PlayFramework 2.5

Tags: forms, playframework-2.0, multi-select

I have a PlayFramework2 application.

attribute list object

```
public class Object
    @ManyToMany
    public List<User> influencers= new ArrayList<>();
```

and then i have a form

```
@select(
     field = campaignForm("influencers.id"),

    options(User.getAffiliatesListOptions(advertiser,Status.ACCEPTED)),
    '_label -> Messages("campaign.affiliates"),
    'class -> "tags",
    'multiple -> "multiple"
  )
```

when I submit form I have no error and I have value

```
influencers.id[0]=1
```

but when I do

```
Form<Object> object = CAMPAIGN_FORM.bindFromRequest();
```

the data is empty

```
BeanList size[0] list[]
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

what i have done is clearly not a good practice

```
Map<String, String> map= CAMPAIGN_FORM.bindFromRequest().data();
        List<User> publishers=new ArrayList<>();
        List<User> influencers=new ArrayList<>();
        map.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if(key.contains("publishers")) {
                publishers.add(new User(Long.parseLong(value)));
            }
        });

        map.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if(key.contains("influencers")) {
                influencers.add(new User(Long.parseLong(value)));
            }
        });
        campaign.setPublishers(publishers);
        campaign.setInfluencers(influencers);
```

there is no sexy method ? or simply ? because it is not efficient at all !